# Pick next value from string on mouse click

Tags: c#, string, list, csv, unity-game-engine

This might be a newbie question, but I really need some advice.
For the project I'm working on, I need to export some parameters into csv file. On mouse click, I need to get: display x coordinate, display y coordinate, first number from string, second number from string. I'm fine with getting this so far.

The question is, how can I get {x, y, 3rd number from string, 4th number from string}; {x, y, 5th number from string, 6th number from string} and so on with every next mouse click? I was trying to do something with `[index-1] [index+1]`but without success so far.

Would be happy to get any advice. Thank you in advance!

```
public class SendToCsv : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<string[]> rowData = new List<string[]>();
    public List<string> UV = new List<string>();

    void Start()
    {
        UV.Add("2");
        UV.Add("4");
        UV.Add("6"); //Here I add more numbers of course
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            string[] rowDataTemp = new string[4];
            rowDataTemp[0] = Input.mousePosition.x.ToString("F4"); // X
            rowDataTemp[1] = Input.mousePosition.y.ToString("F4"); // Y
            rowDataTemp[2] = UV[1];
            rowDataTemp[3] = UV[2];

            rowData.Add(rowDataTemp);

            string[][] output = new string[rowData.Count][];

            for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
            {
                output[i] = rowData[i];
            }

            int length = output.GetLength(0);
            string delimiter = ",";

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, output[index]));

            string filePath = getPath();

            StreamWriter outStream = System.IO.File.CreateText(filePath);
            outStream.WriteLine(sb);
            outStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `index` and `index+1` and everytime you click do `index += 2`

Comment: Hi Ivanshv, Can you highlight your code with some useful comment, we want to know where are you reading 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th... number from string and what do you mean by *number from string*

Comment: You need to add a integer property to the class index.  Then every time you click the button get the index value and then increase/decrease value.  Also check to make sure you do not exceed the size of the array.